# How can I get the active tab in a Powerpoint application?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

Please I have some questions about:

**1/** How can I get the active tab in a Powerpoint application?
for example : **TabHome** is activate or **TabInsert**

**2/** How can I know if the PowerPoint backstage is open?
I used the onHide and onShow events but both are running only once.

`<backstage onHide="backstageOnHide" onShow="backstageOnShow">
      ...
 </backstage>`

I’m using **C#** and **ribbon xml** for a VSTO-PowerPoint project.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not possible with the standard Ribbon UI available in VSTO. If it's possible, then only using the Accessibility APIs, which is non-trivial. Here are links to information: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility-cd7fe67f, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38906/UI-Automation-Using-Microsoft-Active-Accessibility, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb404170(v=office.12), http://www.wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.php

Comment: I note that "User Interface Automation" is supposed to supercede the Accessibility APIs, but find no detailed information on how it works with Office. Here's a link to that deocumentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview